# unable to tigger function through "onchange" on file input sometime

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

unable to tigger function through "onchange" on file input sometime

```
<input type="file" id="{{doc_type}}" file-model="fileObj['{{doc_type.id_type}}']" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().uploadThisFile(id)" />
```

Comment: What do you expect it to do? what is it doing instead? Please give us more information...

Comment: you probably want to call a function using ng-change instead otherwise use a custom directive that binds to onchange event and calls $rootScope.$apply after the function callback is executed.

Comment: actually i found the issue, it is not able to reset the file input if I try to select the another file with different file name it work can any body tell me how to reset the file input